# How to prevent a non-scrollable UIScrollView from stealing scroll event?

Tags: ios, iphone, scroll, uiscrollview, hittest

To elaborate on my question, I've three scrollviews one top of another, let say base, middle and top. Base scroll view's content size is more so it will scroll, middle scrollview's content size is equal to its frame so it will not scroll, top scrollview's content size is more than its frame so it will also scroll.

Now when I scroll the top scrollview, once it reaches its end, I"m expecting it would scroll the base scroll view as middle is not scrollable. But it seems middle scroll view consumes all my scroll events and not letting the scroll event to go to base scroll view.

I"ve tried by setting more content size to middle scrollview, then it working as expected, first top scroll view scrolls fully then it passes the scroll event to middle scroll view then to the base scroll view.

Now it is more evident that middle scrollview (which is non scrollable) is consuming all of my scrolling event from going to base scroll view. How do I prevent that.

Note : As I've to support zooming, I need scroll view in all three levels.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.